# DataTables - Responsive hiding columns on large screens

Tags: datatables, responsive

I have a problem with DataTables - I want to use the responsive add-on to hide columns on smaller screen sizes, unfortunately the responsive add-on is hiding columns on larger screen sizes when it really doesn't need to.

Here is my javascript code:

```js
    var table = $('#peopleTable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl,
            dataSrc: function (json) {
                return $.parseJSON(json);
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'name',
                responsivePriority: 1,
                width: '5%',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="<?php echo $localPath;?>/people/person.php?id=' + row.id + '"><img class="icon" title="' + row.people_type + '" src="<?php echo $localPath; ?>/webimg/people-type/b/' + row.people_type_id + '.png">' + row.main_contact + ' @ ' + row.name + '</a>';
                }
            },
            /*{
                data: 'main_contact',
                responsivePriority: 1,
                width: '5%'
            },*/
            { 
                data: 'add1',
                responsivePriority: 1,
                width: '5%',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var output = [];
                    if (row.add1) { output.push(row.add1); }
                    if (row.add2) { output.push(row.add2); }
                    if (row.add3) { output.push(row.add3); }
                    if (row.town) { output.push(row.town); }
                    var outputStr = output.join(', ');
                    return '<span class="address-trunc" title="' + outputStr + '">' + outputStr + '</span>';
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'phone',
                responsivePriority: 1,
                width: '5%'
            },
            /*{
                data: 'email',
                responsivePriority: 1,
                width: '5%',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="mailto:' + row.email + '">' + row.email + '</a>';
                }
            },*/
            {
                data: 'id',
                orderable: false,
                responsivePriority: 1,
                width: '5%',
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var url = '<?php echo $localPath;?>/people/person.php?id=' + row.id;
                    return '<a href="' + url + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">View</a> '
                        <?php if ($activeUser->can('delete')) { ?>
                            + '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary delete-person" data-person="' + row.name + '" data-id="' + row.id + '">Delete</a>'
                        <?php } ?>
                            ;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

As you can see I have been playing about with the code in order to make all the columns appear on a large screen size.

When I started off I had more columns in play (they are now commented out), I had all the widths adding up to 100%, and I have all the `responsivePriority`s set to correct values (instead of them all being 1).

Reducing the number of columns, setting lower widths, altering `responsivePriority`s - doing all of these things had no effect, on a large screen the responsive add-on was still insisting on hiding at least 1 column.

How do I stop this?  I still want to use the add-on as it is very useful on smaller screens, but I don't want it force the hiding of columns when it doesn't need to.

To show you what is happening, here is a screen shot - you can see the huge almost-empty columns where there is plenty of room for another column - and yet DataTables is insisting on hiding a column behind the `+` symbol on the far left.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responsive extension has many [classes](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes) to configure when columns should be visible/hidden.

You could use `desktop` class to specify columns shown for window width greater than or equal to 1024 px.

See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/classes.html) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use

```js
var table = $('#peopleTable').DataTable({
  responsive: window.innerWidth < 1000 ? true : false,
  ...
})
```

I mean simply not initialize the responsive extension when it is not needed. `1000` is just a suggestion, "larger screen sizes" is relative :)

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8vtqsf7z/**